# How to fix timezone in Container Generated by Docker Build

Tags: docker, timezone, ubuntu-18.04

Sorry I am a newbie to `docker` and `docker-compose`.

The "saved" container does not show correct timezone.

Background:

1. because of company constraint, I cannot put the Dockerized *SpringBoot* Application to a Host B.
2. My Boss tells me to Dockerized *SpringBoot* Application in Host A.
3. Save the `docker save $imageName > application.tar` in Host A
4. Load the Saved Image `docker load < application.tar` in Host B
5. Run the Docker image in Host B...
6. Host A and Host B are in same timezone (Hong Kong Time)

Result:

1. The timezone inside container (check log result) find the log time is correct (Hong Kong timezone, UTC+8) in Host A
   (no matter it is triggered by `docker run` or `docker compose`)
2. The timezone inside the container (check log result) find the log time is WRONG (UTC+0) in Host B
   (no matter it is triggered by `docker run` or `docker compose`)

docker version
Client:
Version:         1.13.1
API version:     1.26
Package version: docker-1.13.1-88.git07f3374.el7.x86_64
Go version:      go1.10.2
Git commit:      07f3374/1.13.1
Built:           Thu Dec  6 07:01:49 2018
OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
docker-py version: 3.6.0
CPython version: 3.6.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

Host A Ubuntu Version
18.04.3

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /root/flexi/
COPY ./target/foo.jar /root/flexi/

### an alpine based image you have to install the tzdata first #### 
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata


### ENV TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong
### RUN echo "Europe/Stockholm" > /etc/timezone
### RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
### Not work for ubuntu to dpkg-reconfigure


VOLUME /log

ADD db.properties /root/flexi
EXPOSE 9988
RUN sh -c 'touch foo.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "foo.jar"]
```

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  foos:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: foos
    ports:
      - "9555:9988"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong
    networks:
      - network1
    volumes:
      - /log:/log
networks:
  network1:
```

```
docker build -t foos .
```

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}'  foos
--> Shows UTC time (in both Host A and Host B)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Set Timezone Using environment variables**

- The timezone of a container can be set using an environment variable

> docker run -e TZ=America/New_York ubuntu date

- the time zone data package tzdata needs to be installed in the container
- configure an NTP server to ensure that the time zones are synced in containers

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
# install tzdata ref. https://serverfault.com/a/992421/41015
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install tzdata

RUN cp -r -f /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Hong_Kong /etc/localtime
```

if not run this command , the build  image does not contain /etc/timezone, therefore it use UTC time.

---

Details

```
### COPY /etc/timezone      /ect/timezone
### fail. It cannot copy the file to the container internally

################################################
## No luck to execute dpkg-reconfigure for UBUNTU 18.0.4.3
################################################
## ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
### RUN dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
OR
### RUN sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
################################################

################################################
## no use
################################################
ENV TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong
### RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
################################################

################################################
## no use
################################################
## RUN echo "Asia/Hong_Kong" > /config/etc/timezone
################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that are running a container with a spark context, you will need to [add the env variable to the spark context](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables).

In databricks, you can do this through [spark_env_vars](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster#spark_env_vars), more [documentation here too](https://docs.databricks.com/en/compute/configure.html#environment-variables).

Ex: `TZ="UTC"`